# Deploy Delphi XE7 app to iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, delphi, ios8, xcode6

Im going the process of setting up my Delphi XE7 to create iPhone apps.

The environment is :

- Delphi XE7
- New Mac - OS X Yosemite
- XCode 6.1.1 (6A2008a)
- iPhone 4 running iOS 8.1 (ie I updated the OS to the latest version)

Ive followed the demos, obtained an Entreprise License from Apple etc

iPhone has Provisioning Profile assigned to it.  When I go XCode -> Device, It shows the Provisioning Profile installed.
When I run to the simulator, all goes well :-)

When I run to my iOS Device (iPhone running iOS 8.1) I receive the following error message :

> Unable to install package : e8000097

I cant seem to find any info on what the error code actually means, to help track down the fault.

Does anyone recognise the error code `e8000097`?

This error is generated when I build my app within the Delphi IDE.

Comment: Create a test project in Xcode and get it deploying to the device. Once you have that working being able to deploy via Delphi can usually follow pretty quick. Are you deploying to Ad Hoc or Debug? Is it IOS 8.1.3?

Comment: Trying to deploy as Debug for now. iOS = 8.1.2

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run to an iOS 8 device as "debug", but you can deploy to the device as an adhoc build and then put lots of debug messages into you app.

Have a look at this blog:
http://blogs.embarcadero.com/sarinadupont/2015/01/29/ios-813-app-deployment-steps-for-xe7

I ended up editing the entitlements file so that all the text is on 1 long line with absolutely no line breaks at all.  That worked for me (after many days of trial and error)